# Showing error your content must have a listView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using `Fragment`. There is no `ListView` used . There is simple `TextView` and `EditText`. But still it showing error Your content must have a `ListView` whose id attribute is `android.R.id.list`? This is issue in android 4.04 only .

Comment: Is your activity extending a ListActivity or are you using a ListFragment?

Comment: Post some code so easy to give answer